# Which hotel chains offer paid membership for their elite status?

Tags: hotels, loyalty-programs

Which hotel chains offer paid membership for their elite status?

Usually to get to an Elite status with a hotel chain you have to accumulate a certain number of stays or points. I wonder if there are hotels that offer immediate paid upgrades to Elite status.

Answer (score 7):

As of now (Feb 2018), I'm aware of these hotel chains where this is possible:

**1. [AccorHotels Group](https://www.accorhotels.com/gb/leclub/program/loyalty-program.shtml) (Ibis, Novotel, Sofitel, Mercure, etc)**

[Ibis Business](http://www.ibis.com/business/ibis-business-card/index.en.shtml): for 90 EUR/year you get Gold status with AccorHotels with 
all the benefits, like free room upgrades, free fruits, welcome drink, early or late checkout. Plus 5-10% discounts off of their regular rates.

[Ibis Business Plus](https://www.accorhotels.com/gb/support/loyalty-membership/accor-favorite-guest-business/faq.shtml): 170 EUR/year gets you Gold and larger discounts at AccorHotels Group hotels

**2. [IHG group](https://www.ihg.com/rewardsclub/content/gb/en/enjoy-rewards) (Holiday Inn, InterContinental, Crowne Plaza, etc)**

[InterContinental Ambassador](https://www.ihg.com/intercontinental/content/us/en/ambassador#): for 200 USD/year you get Gold Elite benefits (which are pretty minimalistic) at all IHG hotels and special benefits like room upgrades, complimentary fruits or snacks only at InterContinental hotels.

---

*Not a paid "upgrade" but can be combined with the above:*

**3 [Hilton Hotels and Resorts](http://www3.hilton.com/en/index.html) (Hilton, Waldorf Astoria, Double Tree, etc**)

[Hilton Honors](http://hiltonhonors3.hilton.com/en/index.html): Runs a *permanent* (it's been active at least for the last couple of years as of the beginning of 2018) [status match program](https://statusmatch.hiltonhonors.com/) against most of the hotel loyalty programs. Sometimes they would match you without any conditions, sometimes you have to complete several stays within a given timeframe to confirm your status match.

Comment: If you get the Chase IHG credit card, you get automatic IHG Platinum Elite status ([one step up from Gold](https://www.ihg.com/rewardsclub/content/us/en/enjoy-rewards)). You have to "pay" for it via the $49 annual fee on the card, but it beats the $200 option. It also includes one free night annually.

Comment: For UK residents IHG have a similar deal: get an IHG Master Card, get Platinum status.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Unfortunately I don't have that option in Russia but it definitely beats Ambassador program.